# How to show facebook updates in the website?

Tags: php, facebook

I am developing a site for mobile company. They want me to show their facebook updates in the website. How do i do that? Please help me?

Comment: Read http://developers.facebook.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this jQuery plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/facebook-wall

I also extended it to allow Like/Comment, like the real Facebook wall.
Really nice for adding the Facebook feed to your site.

p.s. Hoping you will accept an answer this time :)

Comment: Thanks Elad. Am trying it out.

Comment: I'm sure you will enjoy it :)